# CORS Origin issue using ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, graphql

I am encountering a weird CORS issue when using C# ASP.NET Core 3.1 and GraphQL (Version="3.3.2"). In the `Startup.cs` file, I have setup the UseCors like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseCors (x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin ()
                .AllowAnyMethod ()
                .AllowAnyHeader ());
            ...
}
```

And also create a `ConfigureCors` function like this:

```
private void ConfigureCors(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var requestOrigins = Configuration.GetSection("RequestOrigins")?
                .GetChildren()
                .Select(url => url.Value)
                .ToArray() ?? new string[] {};
            
    services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: AllowSpecificOrigins,
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins(requestOrigins)
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowCredentials()
                            .AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
            });
}
```

Called the `ConfigureCors` like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
         ConfigureCors(services);
         ...
}
```

In `appsetting.{env}.json`, I set the `RequestOrigins`:

```
"RequestOrigins": [
    "http://localhost:8889"
  ]
```

When using frontend React to call the mutation like this:

```
const link = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'https://localhost:5001/graphql/v1',
  fetchOptions: {
    credentials: 'include'
  },
  headers : {Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('Token')}`}
})

export default new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache
});
```

It will throw the CORS issue:

> Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:5001/graphql/v1' from origin 'http://localhost:8889' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

However the backend log shows:

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
> Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS https://localhost:5001/graphql/v1
>
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
> CORS policy execution successful.

I am very confused:

1. Why are the `OPTIONS` not the `POST`, since I am calling a graphql mutation?
2. Why backend shows CORS policy execution successful, but frontend got CORS blocker?

However, if I commented out the Authentication part like this:

```
const link = new HttpLink({
      uri: 'https://localhost:5001/graphql/v1',
      //fetchOptions: {
        //credentials: 'include'
      //},
      //headers : {Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('Token')}`}
    })
```

Got the authorization failed error, but not CORS blocker. The token I have validated work in Postman. If I remove the `app.UseCors`, the CORS blocker comes back which is understandable. My guess is some CORS related configuration I didn't do right, but not sure which part, anyone knows what's going on? Thanks a lot!

Comment: **CORS** (cross-origin resource sharing) - not "CROS" ...

Comment: Might be an issue with SSL.

Comment: app.UseCors seems to be missing AllowCredentials()

Comment: "Why are the OPTIONS not the POST," - because as the error message says, this is the *preflight* request. If you don't know what the preflight request is, you ought to read up more on how CORS works.

Answer (score 2):

based on Microsoft Doc's in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) when ever u add new policy u need to specify that policy to app.UseCors().
and also pay attention to this

> The call to UseCors must be placed after UseRouting, but before UseAuthorization. For more information, see Middleware order.

Comment: Hi Pouya, thanks a lot. It's exactly what I missed. After adding the urls in add.UseCors(). It worked.